# ruby on rails - CSS for a partial

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website using Ruby on Rails. Right now, I've added a `bootstrap` navigation bar in a partial file, "`_navheader.html.erb"` in my `layouts` folder. I render the partial right after the `body` tag in `application.html.erb`. The problem is that I have some CSS code for the nav bar in a separate css file. How do I link the CSS file, `navheader.css.scss` to the html file, `_navheader.html.erb`?

Answer (score 6):

In your `application.html.erb`'s head section, you can write

```
<% if content_for?(:head) %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
<% end %>
```

And in your `_navheader.html.erb`, you define your css file (with respective path) like this:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/navheader.css.scss"> 
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @user2771150 It is dynamic way of adding contents to your `<head>` section from views.